# jQuery in Angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an array of entities in Angular.js app, each have an `id` and `parentId` attributes and I need to show them as a tree using jQuery.

```
Look at the code and the result - http://jsfiddle.net/2M6ny/6/
```

First I wait the list of entities to be rendered. Then I need to restructure elements.
The thing is, when I iterate through the list of items, trying to get the data- attribute, Angular gives me this: `{{process.enter}}`. jQuery code like `$('.processes .process').first().data('parent')` causes the same result.

Is there a way to get the data of the DOM element in this case?

The needed result is a list like:

```
First Level Process #1
    Second Level Process #1
    Second Level Process #2
First Level Process #2
    Second Level Process #3
```

Comment: Don't do that, you have directives for the DOM manipulations.

Comment: Could you teach me them?

Comment: You can start here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Teach you about directives is a long path, but you can start looking at: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-first-directive and https://egghead.io/search?q=directive

Comment: Have a look at the functions `element` and `foreach` in the `angular` object.